# Keep Internet Explorer browser in front after being opened from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I open an Internet Explorer window when I launch Outlook 2010.

The opened IE browser is pushed to the back after Outlook completes launching.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

    OpenIE

End Sub

Sub OpenIE()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    'If (ie) Then
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
        AppActivate ie
    'End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to make the IE browser stay in front until users manually close it?

In other words, can I open an IE browser that behaves like a "Modal dialog"?

My thought is to open a form instead, (or container) and embed the IE browser inside the form.

I am a web developer and have no experience in macro development.

Comment: The IE browser is another application, with its own top-level window. You certainly can't make *that* behave like a modal dialog, not without serious Win32 hacks. As for embedding the browser in the form, you'll need an appropriate ActiveX component for that, ...which probably isn't going to be up-to-date with the latest security patches. I think the best solution involves the actual IE browser window, and some Win32 API calls to grab that window and bring it to the front when your macro completes... but then, Outlook will want to keep focus after the `Startup` handler completes... hmm...

Comment: Embedded IE browser wouldn't be out of date - it is the same  IE that the user launches standalone.

Comment: `ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMinimized` in `Application_Startup`gets Outlook out of the way. It may be sufficient to keep a user focused on IE.